# Scrolling DIV causing browser lag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently building a tour for a website and the last step of the tour is to be able to select different topics done with hidden checkboxes and then pictures that you can click on with the label tag you can see it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/58t6xfqc0tz4zgc/Screenshot%202014-06-30%2014.03.57.png

For some reason scrolling up and down a few times causing the entire browser to freeze for a few seconds and im not sure what could be causing it.

Have anyone else experienced this?

Im using the following code to enable the scroll of the div

```
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Ive tested all my javascript events and nothing is being triggered by the scroll so that shouldn't be it either.

Comment: What browser, is it firefox by any chance?

Comment: Try creating a new GPU layer by adding `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to it and see if it scrolls smoother.

Comment: Ive tried in both Safari and Chrome both lagging massivly. Still lags with -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);

Comment: Firefox has no lag at all

Comment: Update: The translateZ seems to have reduced the lag but not removed it

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to the css of the div

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Jun/01/Smoothing-out-div-scrolling-in-Mobile-WebKit-Browsers